# Reproduce pip-installed-pytorch environment using conda

Tags: pip, pytorch, conda

I've been wondering what is the best way to create a env.yaml file while using conda.

I created a conda env for object detection use case, then use this command to create the env.yaml file
`conda env export --no-builds | findstr -v "prefix" > env.yaml`
Which yields

```
name: yolov8_custom
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ...
  pip:
    - ...
    - torch==2.0.1+cu118
    - torchvision==0.15.2+cu118
    - ...
```

The env was created and all the dependencies installed by conda was successfully installed, however, it keeps failing when installing the dependencies installed with pip

`conda env create --name envname --file=env.yaml`

The error said it can't find torch and torch vision with that version.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==2.0.1+cu118 (from versions: 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==2.0.1+cu118

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

My question is
What is the best practice to recreate an env that initially created using conda AND pip

note: I installed pytorch using pip because it keeps failing when I use conda.

Answer (score 0):

### Work from YAML

The best practice is that one specifies the environment from a YAML *at environment creation* and only updates the environment *through* the YAML. *Post hoc* generation of YAML on mixed environments is unreliable and particularly breaks down when using Pip to install from non-PyPI sources, e.g., GitHub or local (see [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9308)).